# Can I use Flex Builder 3 with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: apache-flex, macos, osx-lion

There are [rumors](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3812963) on the web that Adobe's Flex Builder 3 is incompatible with Mac OS X Lion. Is that true or can I upgrade to Lion and keep using Flex Builder 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex Builder 3 is not compatible with Lion, nor are most later FlashBuilder releases.  The most recent version of Flash Builder(4.5.1) has had a lot of work done by the Adobe team to fix those issues, and they have recently (July 27th) released an updated guidance on the remaining issues.

http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/07/updated-guidance-on-flash-builder-4-5-compatibility-with-mac-os-x-10-7.html

Adobe does not recommend updating to Lion for owners of the earlier products, as mentioned in the guidance.

Comment: Did anyone try it out really? I'd bet there is nothing so special in Adobe's Eclipse customization for Flex Builder 3 that could prevent it from running on Lion. In the end it boils down to Java mostly which should still be compatible... Or do I miss something?

Comment: Folks, I have just updated to Lion and it still seems to work. The only thing that appears to be defunct now is the adobe updater plugin (due to missing Rosetta). But I don't need that anyway.

Comment: @Tobias: I do not already have Flex Builder 3 installed and I'm using Lion.  The installer is a PPC app that requires Rosetta (which is no longer supported in Lion).  I assume you already had Flex Builder 3 installed?  Could you do a `find` in your Flex Builder 3 app directory so that I might try expanding the installer archive manually?

Comment: I can also confirm that Flex builder 3 does work on Lion. I upgraded my macbook pro that already had flex on it about a month ago everything seems to work fine. I just get a warning when I first launch the app "... can't open aum.flexbuilder.osx because PowerPC..." but I don't seem to have any issues running it. However I'm interested it hearing if you're able to install it directly to Lion (looking at getting a new mac soon). Could you post your findings?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to install FB3 on OS X Lion. The problem is not the FB3, but the InstallAnywhere package. Here's how...

1. I found another app that has a "JavaApplicationStub" that worked on Lion. I used Cinderella (http://cinderella.de/files/release/Cinderella2.zip).
2. Find the app that works in the Finder. Right-click (Control-click) and choose "Show Package Contents". Go to the Contents/MacOS directory. Copy "JavaApplicationStub" to your Desktop.
3. Copy the "FB3_Mac_Installer.app" from the dmg onto your Desktop.
4. Right-click (Control-click) and choose "Show Package Contents" on "FB3_Mac_Installer". Go to the Contents/MacOS directory.
5. Copy the "JavaApplicationStub" from the Desktop to the FB3_Mac_Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/ folder. Delete the executable named "FB3_Mac_Installer"
   and rename "JavaApplicationStub" to "FB3_Mac_Installer"
6. Run the FB3_Mac_Installer.app on your Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

No, Flex Builder 3 is not compatible with Lion.